# Getting SyntaxError on pass=self.Entry1.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I was trying to create a program that accepts password in Tkinter, but I'm unable to save the password into a variable

There is a SyntaxError in this line

```py
pass = self.Entry1.get()
```

```py
def tk_start_gui():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    top = DProgram(root)
    root.mainloop()

def password(type):
    global passroot
    passroot = Tk()
    top = PassProgram(passroot, type)

class PassProgram:
    def __init__(self, top=None, passtype=None):
        bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'

        top.geometry("300x100+480+222")
        top.title("Enter Password")
        top.configure(background=bgcolor)

        self.Frame1 = LabelFrame(top)
        self.Frame1.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.02, relheight=0.94,relwidth=0.96)
        self.Frame1.configure(text='Enter Password')
        self.Frame1.configure(relief=GROOVE)
        self.Frame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.Frame1.configure(relief=GROOVE)
        self.Frame1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Frame1.configure(width=575)

        self.Label1 = Label(self.Frame1)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01)
        self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Enter password to access {}settings'''.format(passtype))

        self.Entry1 = Entry(self.Frame1)
        self.Entry1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.1)
        self.Entry1.configure(width=46)
        self.Entry1.configure(show="*")
        self.Entry1.bind("<Return>", self.on_change)
        self.Entry1.pack(side=LEFT)

    def on_change(self, *args):
        pass = self.Entry1.get()
        print("function passed")
        self.Entry1.delete(0, 'end')
tk_start_gui()
```

Comment: `pass` is a reserved word in Python, you cannot use it as a variable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].  This is both missing parts (for instance, `DProgram` is not defined) and including unneeded details (window decorations).

Comment: Ok, it was the "pass" thanks Goyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pass = self.Entry1.get()
```

pass is a reserved variable in python use:

```
code = self.Entry1.get()
```